# C++ Censoring a specific word within a character array

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

I have a homework assignment for my C++ class where I need to read in a sentence make a copy of that sentence and then search for the word "hell" and replace it with "heck." The professor gave us a mini-format to follow when writing the program.Note that I cannot use strings in this program only character arrays. Also the sample my professor gave us shows us the parameters we use for each function so I cannot change the parameters. My code write now is as follows:

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <cctype>
        using namespace std;

        const int MAX_LENGTH = 50; //Assume person will not enter a sentence longer than 47 characters
        const int ZERO = 0;
        void GetSentence(char[]);
        void CopySentence(char[], char[]);
        void MakeUpperCase(char[]);
        void InsertBlankStartEnd(char[]);
        char Sentence[MAX_LENGTH + 1] = "";
        char SentenceCopy[MAX_LENGTH + 1] = "";
        GetSentence(Sentence);
        cout << "Original : " << Sentence << "\n";
        while (Sentence[ZERO] != ZERO)
        {
            //Copy's a sentence while keeping the original (works).
            CopySentence(SentenceCopy, Sentence);
            cout << "Censored : " << SentenceCopy << endl;
            //Converts all elements in SentenceCopy to Uppercase (works)
            MakeUpperCase(SentenceCopy);
            //inserts a blank before the sentence and after the sentence
            InsertBlankStartEnd(SentenceCopy);
            cout << SentenceCopy << endl;
            Sentence[ZERO] = 0;
        }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void GetSentence(char Sentence[])
{
    cout << "Enter a sentence ==> " << endl;
    cin.getline(Sentence, MAX_LENGTH + 1);
}
void CopySentence(char Copy[], char Original[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; Original[i]; i++)
    {
        Copy[i] = Original[i];
    }

}
void MakeUpperCase(char Copy[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; Copy[i]; i++)
    {
        Copy[i] = toupper(Copy[i]);
    }
}
void InsertBlankStartEnd(char Copy[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; Copy[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        Copy[i + 1] = Copy[i];
        Copy[0] = ' ';
    }
}
```

I know the code is not complete but I want to finish my InsertBlankStartEnd function before moving on to the other ones. The program was working fine up until the InsertBlankStartEnd function and I believe it is because I am going beyond the array scope range. All the program does now is crash when I try to debug it.

Comment: "I can't use pointers" – well then you're gonna have a hard time solving this task. `void GetSentence(char[]);` is already a function with pointer parameter.

Comment: Whoops I meant pointers as in * variable. I should change that.

Comment: Don't let him censor your ability to use strings!